# CRC32とMD5の使い分け

Tags: アルゴリズム, ハッシュ, md5

CRC32とMD5はハッシュアルゴリズム？として、どちらもよく利用されていると思います。

けれど、その使い分けはどのように行われているのですか？

Answer (score 15):

CRC は巡回冗長検査
- ハードウエアで実装が容易
- 計算結果が小さい (CRC-32 なら 32bit)
- 逆方向演算を困難にするようには設計されていない
- 伝送誤りの検出に向く
- 改ざんの検出には向かない
- 計算方法 (計算式) がいっぱいある (標準化されてない)

(暗号論的)単方向ハッシュ (MD5 は古いので SHA 推奨)
- 計算量が多い（ハードウエア実装には向かない）
- 計算結果が大きい (MD5 で 128bit SHA256 で 256bit)
- 逆方向演算がきわめて困難になるよう設計されている
- 伝送誤りの検出に使うにはコスト高
- 改ざんの検出も可能 (正しく運用できる限り)
- 計算方法が標準化されている

実際問題として
- CRC は短い電文の伝送誤りをハードウエアレベルで検出する目的に使われることが多い
- 単方向ハッシュはソフトウエアレベルで改ざん防止・逆変換防止に使われることが多い

と理解してそんなにまちがってない・・・と思うです。